# Changing osd while there are inconsistent objects inside

Tags: ceph

I have a disk in my cluster that started giving out pg read errors after scrubs the last 2 days. Manual repairs are taking too much time and the disk's smartctl output does not look good. My question is, can i change disks before the errors are fixed? Will it cause some corruption across cluster? every pg is active+clean, only some pgs (erasure coded) are active+clean+inconsistent. Should i start recovery process and then replace the osd?

PS: none of the data chunks with read error are the primary chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, I answer how I understand it.
The safest way to replace a failed disk is to let ceph rebalance after the disk has been taken out and then let it remap after the new disk has been deployed. This is lots of network traffic and can take quite some time, but you reduce the risk of data loss.
There are ways to prevent ceph from backfilling and deploy a new disk in a degraded state, but this increases the risk of a disk failure during this degraded state which can lead to data loss. I would advise against it, though.

You write

> "can I change disks before the errors are fixed?"

How many disks have failed? The PG availability is dependent on `k + 1` active chunks for erasure coded pools (pool's `min_size`).

> "Manual repairs are taking too much time"

You mean `ceph pg repair <PG_ID>`? Usually I would wait for it, it can help, not all scrub errors are corrupted data, but in your case with the smartctl output it's probably just a temporary fix, if it even succeeds.

Comment: The elements in grown defect list count and uncorrected errors kept increasing overtime which caused very very high latencies on the disk occasionally which resulted in automatic osd reboots. Which i think is the indicator of an entire disk failure in a very near future. The problem with repairing pgs was after entering the command and waiting for hours nothing started, meanwhile there were new scrub errors on the same osd being added. The EC Pool is formatted 3+2 by the way. Eventually we just destroyed the osd and started the recovery process a couple of hours after asking this question.